# Windows Phone 7 Mango (7.1) - Background Task not called repeatedly

Tags: c#, background, windows-phone-7

I am using Background task to perform activity when application is not running. Below is my sample code that should be called every 30 mins and add the timestamp to the file on Isolated Storage. The problem is that, background task (OnInvoke event) is called only at the time I am adding it (ScheduledActionService.Add(periodicTask);). It is not called every 30 mins.

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists("testbg.txt"))
    {
        EditExistingFile("testbg.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
    }
    else
    {
        CreateNewFile("testbg.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}

NotifyComplete();
}

public static void StartBackgroundTask()
{
PeriodicTask periodicTask = new PeriodicTask("Project One Tasks");

// The description is required. This is the string that the user
// will see in the background services Settings page on the device.
periodicTask.Description = "Performs various activities related to Project One.";
periodicTask.ExpirationTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);

// If the agent is already registered with the system,
// call the StopPeriodicAgent helper method.
if (ScheduledActionService.Find(periodicTask.Name) != null)
{
    StopBackgroundTask();
}

ScheduledActionService.Add(periodicTask);
}
```

Edit:

One thing I noticed, when I start Periodic or ResourceIntensive Task, I get following dialog:

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone

### The remote connection to the device has been lost.  Please verify the device connection and restart debugging.

### OK

Anyone getting this message when Tasks are called?

Answer (score 2):

Beta 2 changes this behavior. Have you rechecked (and tested it a Mango phone instead of the emulator)?

Comment: I can't manage to get Mango Device. I am from India. Do you know how to get Mango Device if I am developer from India?

Comment: If you're a registered developer, you were able to upgrade existing devices but I would guess since you're from India that the AppDev membership isn't available yet? Am I wrong about that? You don't need a Mango-specific device.  If you want to contact me through my website, I can let you send me a .xap to test on my Mango device.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind support. I need permission of my bosses. I will ask and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wild guessing here but perhaps you are supposed to re-add the task from within the OnInvoke every time, leaving the task to decide whether a subsequent task call is required.

Comment: I can't find this in Official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

How often are you checking that this is working?
The 30 minutes is not guaratneed and could drift by as much as 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try firing the task again on a much shorter time frame when debugging. While it won't resolve the issue you won't need to wait half an hour to find out what is going on.

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
    // using ...

#if DEBUG
    // If we're debugging, fire the task again
    string taskName = "Project One Tasks";
    ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(taskName, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
#endif

     NotifyComplete();
}
```